# How to draw a cube (3D box) around a point in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

How can I draw a 3D bounding box around a 3D point in Matlab? e.g. plotting a cube (15x15x15) around a 3D point (20,3,10);  the point should be in inside and center of the cube.

Comment: Please add a code block?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that....

Comment: Always add a piece of code!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the six sides of the box to be semi-transparent?  If so, you could use the following:

```
% Center point is at coordinate [ax ay az].
ax = 20;  ay = 3;  az = 10;

% Full-width of each side of cube.
w = 15;

% For readability.
h = w/2;

patch_args = { 'FaceColor', 'b', 'FaceAlpha', 0.3 };

% Side #1 of 6.
patch( 'XData', ax+[-h -h  h  h], 'YData', ay+[-h  h  h -h], 'ZData', az+[-h -h -h -h], patch_args{:} )
daspect( [1 1 1] )  % 1:1:1 aspect ratio.
hold on
% Side #2 of 6.
patch( 'XData', ax+[-h -h  h  h], 'YData', ay+[-h  h  h -h], 'ZData', az+[ h  h  h  h], patch_args{:} )
% Side #3 of 6.
patch( 'XData', ax+[-h -h  h  h], 'YData', ay+[ h  h  h  h], 'ZData', az+[-h  h  h -h], patch_args{:} )
% Side #4 of 6.
patch( 'XData', ax+[-h -h  h  h], 'YData', ay+[-h -h -h -h], 'ZData', az+[-h  h  h -h], patch_args{:} )
% Side #5 of 6.
patch( 'XData', ax+[ h  h  h  h], 'YData', ay+[-h -h  h  h], 'ZData', az+[-h  h  h -h], patch_args{:} )
% Side #6 of 6.
patch( 'XData', ax+[-h -h -h -h], 'YData', ay+[-h -h  h  h], 'ZData', az+[-h  h  h -h], patch_args{:} )

% Red dot in middle.
scatter3( ax, ay, az, 'or', 'filled', 'SizeData', 150 )

hold off
```

If instead you want the six sides to be completely transparent, you could repeat the code above but set `FaceAlpha` to `0.0` instead of `0.3`

Comment: Thanks, how shoud I specify XData, YData, and ZData? I have the middle point (e.g. point A) coordinates and the size of the box. I need to draw a box around the point A in a way A is in middle of the cube.

Comment: I just edited the answer to show how to center the box on an arbitrary 3d coordinate point.  Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Thanks, yes. Now, how  can I define an arbitrary box sizes? e.g. 20x20x20 or 10x10x10 or whatever...

Comment: Just edited to show how to define an arbitrary box size.